# Legend location in R project

Tags: r, plot

I have 4  area for testing the data about related distributions ob R project. I plotted all of them but legends are on the medium of the any plots. Have can i shift them to whichever fit area on the plots. For example, right-down? Thanks in advance!

```
par(mfrow = c(2,2))

plot.legend <-c("weibull","gamma","normal", "lognormal")

denscomp(list(fitweibull,fitgamma,fitnorm,fitlnorm),legendtext = plot.legend)
qqcomp(list(fitweibull,fitgamma,fitnorm,fitlnorm),legendtext = plot.legend)
cdfcomp(list(fitweibull,fitgamma,fitnorm,fitlnorm),legendtext = plot.legend)
ppcomp(list(fitweibull,fitgamma,fitnorm,fitlnorm),legendtext = plot.legend)
```

[image]

Comment: You could use the xlim parameter to create extra space in your graphs to leave room for the legends.

Comment: Welcome to SO! It's usually helpful to provide a completely [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), as well to make it [minimal](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This includes not just providing data or using standard datasets, it also includes letting us know about these functions you're using (I'm not familiar with them and they are not in base R). Please read these two links and then edit your question. Thanks!

Comment: Is this really related to Highcharts? It doesn't look like you are using Highcharts.